# I need help as the blender installer is failing

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install the most recent blender build on my Win-10 PC and keep getting the error:
   Blender Setup Wizard ended prematurely

Blender Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error.  Your system 
     has not been modified.  To install this program at a later time, run 
     Setup Wizard again.

Click the Finish button to exit the Setup Wizard

I've checked the event viewer and not seen anything generated by this attempt.

Can anyone help me?